# Receiving an empty map with no errors when trying to unmarshal a string read from a file (Answer: unmarshal into the data structure itself)

Tags: go, text-files, unmarshalling

I have a file, 'test.txt', containing the following data.  This file was created from the same structures from the code below using marshaling.

```
{"VLETXGJM":{"attrib1":"test1","attrib2":"test2"}}
```

I am trying to read it back from the file and unmarshal it into a map using the same structures.  I can successfully read the data from the file.  I receive no errors when I try to unmarshal it into the map.  However, my map is empty.

The mutex is used to protect the map since my real implementation (this is an extracted test) needs to use a protected map for concurrency.  I have tried this same code removing the sync library and received the same negative result.

The test code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "os"
)

type TestObject struct {
    Attrib1 string `json:"attrib1"`
    Attrib2 string `json:"attrib2"`
}

type TestMap map[string]TestObject

type TestList struct {
    sync.RWMutex
    list TestMap
}

func main() {

    tl := TestList{ list: make(TestMap) }

    // Read the list back out of the file

    fi, err := os.Open("test.txt")

    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        fmt.Println("data file does not exist")
        panic(nil)
    }

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer func() {
        if err := fi.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    data := make([]byte, 1024 * 1024)
    count, err := fi.Read(data)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("read from file: \"%s\"\n",data[:count])

    tl.Lock()
    err = json.Unmarshal(data[:count], &tl)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    tl.Unlock()

    // List it out
    tl.Lock()
    if len(tl.list) == 0 {
        fmt.Println("Empty list")
    } else {
        for key, _ := range tl.list {
            fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", tl.list[key].Attrib1, tl.list[key].Attrib2)
        }
    }
    tl.Unlock()
}
```

The output of the run is:

```
read from file: "{"VLETXGJM":{"attrib1":"test1","attrib2":"test2"}}"
Empty list
```

Thank you for your help.  I have searched for similar issues and not yet found an exact duplicate of this scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to unmarshal into `tl.list` instead of `tl`:

```
err = json.Unmarshal(data[:count], &tl.list)
```

`tl` has no exported fields, so `Unmarshal` into `tl` won't do anything. `tl.list` (i.e., type `TestMap`) matches your data.

Comment: Thank you, Andy.  This was exactly the problem.  Thank you for the help and education.